# Assume the following is a method header in a class: public <T Implement comparable <T> > tT greatest(T arg1, arg2)

Tags: java, generics

I'm having trouble with some of my homework for Java. I just can't grasp the concept of these generics.

The question is:

Assume the following is a method header in a class:

```
public <T implements Comparable <T>>T greatest(T arg1, T arg2)
```

Find the error?

I really don't understand how to go.

Comment: `Implement` neither `implements` is valid... Read [this tutorial about generics](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html).

Comment: sorry typo I corrected it, its early this has been bugging me all night

Comment: ahhh so I can just extend it I mean wouldn't that be more effective anyways instead of implements? What does the T arg1 and the T arg2 do I have never seen that used as a parameter.

Comment: N.B: I rolled back my edit, as misusing `implements` rather than `extends` might be part of the question...

Comment: @ChadBenjamin look up generics, its the normal way

Comment: @ChadBenjamin - I see that you are an IT student.  Considering that your future employers (or their HR consultants) could read what you write here, you would be well advised to pay more attention to the language and clarity of your questions and comments.  1) Avoid teenage stuff like *"Hahah!! I would up it but I have no rep yet lol"*.  2) Ask your Questions clearly.  For instance, until you accepted an answer it was not clear what you wanted us to explain.  A future employer will look (among other things) at your ability to communicate clearly and professionally.  START PRACTICING NOW.

Comment: for best results, use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make that stuff compile you must modify in the following way :

```
public <T extends Comparable <T>> T greatest(T arg1, T arg2)
```

Comparable is an interface but in this context, extends is used to mean either "extends" (for classes) or "implements" (for interfaces).

Comment: I'm probably just being blind, but -- how is that different from the code that the OP posted?

Comment: its not because Comparable is an interface, its because its in a generic declaration. You have to use extends not implements for classes too.

Comment: @ruakh: My bad. I had edited the question a bit too quickly and fixed the keyword misuse...

Comment: how is that different from the code that the OP posted? => I've just wondered the same thing until the question was reedited...

Comment: Thanks guys!! Uhhh im in my second semester of java and each week comes and I get a somewhat of a understanding then we learn something new and it hits me in the face. Hahah!! I would up it but I have no rep yet lol

Answer (score 1):

The error is you can not use keyword implements in a method signature. Only in class declaration.
Both of these compile :

```
 public <T extends Comparable<T>>T greatest(T arg1, T arg2){
     return null;
    }

 public <T extends String>T greatest(T arg1, T arg2){
     return null;
    }
```

Comment: ...sorry i initially wanted to say "Comparable is an interface BUT to make that staff compile..", the reason behind this design decision in Java (to always use extend and to not differentiate) i think was because you don't know the real type of T so you cannot distinguish between the two keywords...

Answer (score 1):

> I need a explanation of this badly as I really dont understand how to go.

Assuming that you want us to explain what the signature means ...

This can be broken down into two parts:

```
public <T ...> T greatest(T arg1, T arg2)
```

This means that `greatest` is a method that takes two instances that are assignment compatible with some type `T`, and returns an instance of the same type.  (And from the name `greatest` is it reasonable to guess that the value that is returned is the greater of the two arguments.)

The second part is this (assuming that the syntax error is corrected):

```
<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

this means that the type `T` must implement the `Comparable` interface with `T` as its type parameter.  Now if you look at the javadocs for Comparable, you will see that it has single method:

```
public int compareTo(T other);
```

which is specified as comparing `this` with `other` and returning a number that is less than zero, zero, or greater than zero depending on whether `this` is (respectively) smaller, equal to or greater than `other`.  (Read the javadoc!)

So basically this is saying that `T` must be a class with a `compareTo` method.  And the obvious intention is that the `greatest` method will *use* the `compareTo` method to figure out which of its 2 arguments is larger ... and return it.

---

As to *explaining* the *syntax*, there are two possible answers:

- The syntax rules are the syntax rules.  You just obey them or your program won't compile.
- The JLS designers had to choose between using `implements` or `extends` in the generic syntax at this point, or using some new keyword or symbol:

  - Adding a new keyword or symbol has too much impact on other parts of the language / tool chain, so they are "out".
  - Allowing either `implements` or `extends` is redundant and likely to lead to unnecessary confusion.
  - There is (IMO) no convincing argument as to which of these choices is better, based on other usages of the `implements` or `extends` keywords.  I wouldn't be surprised if they decided based on a coin toss ...

Comment: I totally agree with you, i have not judged the signature ...but only make it compile. Probably this signature would make more sense : public <T extends Comparable <T>> T greatest(T... args)

Answer (score 0):

With the typo corrected, it compiles fine.

Of course you could make it slightly more flexible using `Comparable<? super T>`.

I once wrote a quite similar utility method you can find here:

http://softsmithy.sourceforge.net/lib/current/docs/api/softsmithy-lib-core/org/softsmithy/lib/util/Comparables.html#max%28T,%20T%29